# How to get continuous repetition of a pattern in a string as a single element

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I am trying to replace the multiple simultaneous repetition of patterns.
Suppose following is the text with the pattern `user`.

`user user please sort situation time bound manner present officer ha moral courage to interest of public of expect political leadership order always absolutely right thing http`

Here I want such occurrence of `user` in this case `user user`  to be replaced with `user` . Condition being that the user repetition should be adjacent to each other.

For example if the sentence was:
`user user user please user user sort situation time bound manner present officer ha moral courage to interest of public of expect political leadership order always absolutely right thing http`
I want `user user user`  and `user user`  each to be replaced with `user`

What I have come up with so far is this:

`re.findall(r'[user\s]+',text)`
I know to replace we will use `re.sub`

The output that I am getting is:

```
['user user user ',
 'e',
 'se user user s',
 'r',
 ' ',
 'u',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' s',
 'u',
 ' ',
 'e ',
 'u',
 ' ',
 'er ',
 'rese',
 ' ',
 'er ',
 ' ',
 'r',
 ' ',
 'ur',
 'e ',
 ' ',
 'eres',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'u',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' e',
 'e',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'e',
 'ers',
 ' ',
 'r',
 'er ',
 's ',
 's',
 'u',
 'e',
 ' r',
 ' ',
 ' ']
```

So I just want the first and the third element to be found and third element should be `user user`  instead of `se user user s`

So when you answer please could you explain how would that expression work. I am very new to regex.

Comment: It should be `re.sub(r'(user\s)+', 'user', text)`, the `[]` brackets define a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Comment: Would the 1st part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73205043/9758194) answer help you out?

Comment: @JvdV No it didnt help. It counts all the words. Or i didnt quite understand it

Comment: @IndrajeetSinghYadav....the 1st part of the answer. With other words...the output1 variable

Comment: @a_guest Yes this worked. Can you give an explaination on how it works? Also if I run findall then i don't get elements like ['user user user','user user'] instead it is ['user','user'].

Comment: @JvdV No i couldnt make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understand your question right. This will shorten `user user` to `user` (even for more repetitions):

```py
import re

s = "user user user please user user sort situation time bound manner present officer ha moral courage to interest of public of expect political leadership order always absolutely right thing http"

s = re.sub(
    r"(?:(\suser\b)|(\buser\s)){2,}",
    lambda g: " user" if g.group(1) else "user ",
    s,
)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
user please user sort situation time bound manner present officer ha moral courage to interest of public of expect political leadership order always absolutely right thing http
```

Comment: Perfect. Can you please explain it a bit what exactly is the expression ```(?:(\suser\b)|(\buser\s)){2,}``` doing? Or how is it working.

Comment: Also this line ```lambda g: " user" if g.group(1) else "user "```

Comment: @IndrajeetSinghYadav You can see the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/Kj5Siy/1). Basically, I want to search for 2 or more same strings (doesn't matter the space is from left or right side).